# Відповідник до слова "хіпі"

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

Хіпі, гіпі або ж хіппі - *міжнародний молодіжний рух, виник у 1965 році у Сан-Франциско в контексті лібералізації і демократизації традиційного суспільства, один з найяскравіших проявів контркультури, мав пацифістське забарвлення, справив істотний вплив на мистецтво, особливо на рок-музику, з ним пов'язані такі поняття, як сексуальна революція, психоделічна революція (джерело - [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%96)).* Поширений цей рух і в Україні, тому можна зустріти статті типу: "[Згадати все. Життя в стилі хіпі](https://24tv.ua/zgadati_vse_zhittya_v_stili_hipi_ukrayinska_versiya_n903465)", "[50 років у стилі хіпі](https://life.pravda.com.ua/society/2016/06/3/213218/)" тощо.

Англійською це слово пишеться "hippie" та походиться від "hip", що в американському сленгу означає "той, що знає" або "той, що розбирається у чомусь".

За відповідником звернувся до Словотвору, однак там не знайшов відповіді (хоч знайшов відповідники до таких субкультур як "хіпстери" ("глямурники"), "скінхеди" ("голомозі), "емо" ("чутливці") тощо). В СУМі також немає цього слова.

Тому виникло питання: "Чи можна знайти чи утворити слово, яке б стало хорошим відповідником?", а також чи взагалі варто перекладати назви субкультур, так як це було зроблено із хіпстерами, скінхедами та емо.